# how to set Firebase Context to use database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have just added firebase database to my app, when the activity is called (after user logs in) i get fatal error

### ProfileActivity.java

```
 import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

    public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //firebase auth object
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Firebase firebase;

    //view objects
    private TextView textViewUserEmail;
    private TextView emailText;
    private Button buttonLogout,button2;
    private EditText nameEdit, ageEdit;
    private DatabaseReference mRootRef;
    private Firebase myFirebaseRef = new          Firebase("https://********************.com");



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       //Previous versions of Firebase
        firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        //Newer version of Firebase
        if(!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }


        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);


        //initializing firebase authentication object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //if the user is not logged in
        //that means current user will return null
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            //closing this activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

        //getting current user
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();



        //initializing views
        textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProfile);
        emailText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
        nameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entername);
        ageEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageedit);
        buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        //displaying logged in user name
        textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome To Your Profile");
        emailText.setText(user.getEmail());

        //adding listener to button
        buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //if logout is pressed
        if(view == buttonLogout){
            //logging out the user
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            //closing activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

        if (view == button2) {

            myFirebaseRef.setValue(nameEdit.getText().toString());
            myFirebaseRef.setValue(ageEdit.getText().toString());

            finish();

            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class));
        }
    }

    }
```

Exception thrown is:

> 12-07 12:42:41.855 26718-26718/com.vb.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.vb.myapplication, PID: 26718
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.vb.myapplication/com.vb.food4thought.ProfileActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using
>   Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android
>   context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.
>                                                                             at com.firebase.client.core.Context.getPlatform(Context.java:45)
>                                                                             at com.firebase.client.core.Context.ensureLogger(Context.java:218)
>                                                                             at com.firebase.client.core.Context.initServices(Context.java:105)
>                                                                             at com.firebase.client.core.Context.freeze(Context.java:92)
>                                                                             at
>   com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getLocalRepo(RepoManager.java:55)
>                                                                             at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getRepo(RepoManager.java:19)
>                                                                             at com.firebase.client.Firebase.(Firebase.java:172)
>                                                                             at com.firebase.client.Firebase.(Firebase.java:177)
>                                                                             at com.firebase.client.Firebase.(Firebase.java:155)
>                                                                             at com.vb.food4thought.ProfileActivity.(ProfileActivity.java:32)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1095)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3084)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

I dont know what im doing wrong. Any help very much appreciated. 
Thankyou.

Comment: You seem to be mixing Firebase 2.x with newer versions of the Firebase SDK. I highly recommend sticking to just the new version and follow the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: which part of my code suggests that? sorry new to android dev and never used firebase

Comment: Many pieces suggest that, first one being `import com.firebase.client.Firebase; import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;` The first line is the 2.x SDK, the next one is 9 or higher. As said: use the documentation I linked, throw the other code out.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, That right there is the trouble with googling tutorials lol. you dont know which is "newer"

Comment: When in doubt, start with the documentation of the people that created the technology: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup. There's a handy codelab too: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/

Comment: see this is another thing right here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#3 it talks you through intergrating firebase, but.. android studio now intergratres everything for you.. which is how i did mine. lol

Answer (score 0):

for either new or old  version you need to first set

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());
```

then you can move for enabling or disabling persistance